# How can I split rows into one row for each element in a JSON array stored in a column?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, open-json

*Okay, so, this is hard to explain but I'll give it a shot. Google didn't help me so please update this question if it can help someone else.*

**Background**

I have a table, *Persons*, with some columns like [ID], [Name] and [PhoneNumbers]. The table is being filled with data from a third party system, so I cannot alter the way we insert data.

The column [PhoneNumbers] contains a JSON array of numbers, like this:

```
{"phonenumbers":[]}
```

I am now trying to write a view against that table, with the goal of having one row for each number.

**Question**

Can I achive this using T-SQL and it's JSON support? I am using SQL Server 2016.

Comment: *"Can I achive this using T-SQL and it's JSON support?"* Yes, what was wrong with `OPENJSON`? Your Google search *will* have lead you to its documentation.

Comment: I've been trying, but I haven't succeed to understand how I can reach my desired behavior. I have no problem extracting the data, but when it comes to create multiple rows of it - I'm stuck. I might be bad at describing my problem, but pleas, atleast point me  in a direction where I can find the answer. A downvote is unecessary before the problem is *correctly* defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @j nvarchar(max) = N'{"phonenumbers":["1a", "2b", "3c", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10x"]}';

select value, *
from openjson(@j, '$.phonenumbers');

declare @t table
(
id int identity,
phonenumbers nvarchar(max)
);

insert into @t(phonenumbers)
values(N'{"phonenumbers":["1a", "2b", "3c", "4d"]}'), (N'{"phonenumbers":["22", "23", "24", "25"]}'), (N'{"phonenumbers":[]}'), (NULL);

select id, j.value, j.[key]+1 as phone_no_ordinal, t.*
from @t as t
outer apply openjson(t.phonenumbers, '$.phonenumbers') as j;
```

Comment: This was EXTREMELY useful! Thanks alot! And also, extra kudos for the response time.

Comment: Fantastic - Thank you!